# Error 401 : Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to add my custom API key and Oauth 2.0 ID. However I keep getting this error

"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."

When I use APIs Explorer Credentials it works fine.

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Hi Recluse were you able to find a solution to fix these errors?